# Check two files are present on two different directories and pick the latest one

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I have below two file of below patterns in two directories say NAS and FTP

```
GE_REF_DATA*
GE_CUST_DET_DATA*
```

There can be files of the above pattern of previous dates as well.

I have to first check in the /NAS path if the file is present there.
If yes, i need to pick the file names and store it in variable like below:

```
var1=`ls -t GE_REF_DATA* | head -n 1`
var2=`ls -t GE_CUST_DET_DATA* | head -n 1`
```

The file has to be of latest date.

If it's not at NAS, i need to check at FTP path /FTP and do the exact same thing.
There is a possibility that only one file exist at NAS/FTP.

I tried the below, but this is also not working.
What is wrong in the below?

```
 cd /NAS
#var1=`ls -t GE_REF_DATA* | head -n 1`
#var2=`ls -t GE_CUST_DET_DATA* | head -n 1`

if [ -f /NAS/"GE_REF_DATA*".txt ] && [ -f /NAS/"GE_CUST_DET_DATA*".txt ]; then
var1=`ls -t GE_REF_DATA* | head -n 1`
var2=`ls -t GE_CUST_DET_DATA* | head -n 1`

echo "Files present at  NAS"
cd /FTP
elif [ -f /FTP/"GE_REF_DATA*".txt ] && [ -f /FTP/"GE_CUST_DET_DATA*".txt ]; then
var1=`ls -t GE_REF_DATA* | head -n 1`
var2=`ls -t GE_CUST_DET_DATA* | head -n 1`

echo "Files present at FTP"

echo $var1
echo $var2

else
echo "Files not present anywhere"

fi
```

Comment: You need to be more clear: _ i need to check at FTP path_ : What is this supposed to mean? And at which point did you get stuck?

Comment: `if [ -f NAS/GE_REF_DATA*.txt ]` is not a good approach.  If more than one file matches the glob, it will be an error.

Comment: There are two paths  /NAS and /FTP. Basically i trying to get two files from these path if they exist into the two variables as mentioned. First need to check in NAS, if found they exit the if, then check the FTP.

Comment: Side note: `elif if` introduces an extra level of nesting that's almost certainly not necessary.

Comment: @BenjaminW.-- Please ignore the typo.

Comment: What do you want to do if only one of the files exists?  Do you want to select the extant pair from the other directory, or a slightly older matching pair from the primary directory, or do you just want the single file of the unmatched pair?

Comment: @WilliamPursell-- yes, that remains a challenge as well.

Comment: @WilliamPursell-- I just want a single file whichever matches and put it into the variables.

Comment: Tried the mentioned approach but that is also not working. Can anyone please let me know what is wrong here?

Comment: @Amit : is the file is arrived at both the paths daily then write some infinite loop that will run continusly and check for file and from both which is the latest pick that and store to variable seems like its a company requiremnet if thats the case get in touch with me will help you in implementing

Comment: Bash can “natively” compare file age for you. For example, `if [[ older_file -ot newer_file ]]; then ...; fi`. It also has a reasonably well-defined behavior when one of the files doesn’t exist, geared towards scripts that try to sync files based on modification dates. Check the `man` page.